# Information_schema appearing in slow_log

Tags: mysql-5.7, information-schema, google-cloud-sql

I am finding that my information_schema keeps running this query

`SELECT engine, COUNT(*) as n FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine is not null GROUP BY engine`

Which seems to always appear in the slow_log, it seems to run every 4-5 seconds; with a 10 second query time.

I am using Google Cloud SQL.

Is there a way I can disable this from occurring - or rather, what keeps triggering it? I have read the MySQL Documentation on the information_Schema but could not figure out why this was being called.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, Google App Engine runs the query for monitoring